# is it possible to include conditional logic within Rspec tags

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

Is it possible to include conditional logic within an Rspec2 tag so that I can run all examples with tags less than or equal to a given value?

Something like:

```
  rspec Dummy_spec.rb --tag version:= <=2
```

Obviously, this doesn't work but is there some Ruby magic that would make this work?

The reason for doing so is that I want to version my Rspec examples using tags.  More specifically, I want to be able to filter all examples with a tag that is equal to or less than the tag value I specify when running the examples.

For example, if I am working on version 2 of my code but also getting a jump start on version 3, then I want to be able to just run all the examples that would be applicable to version 1 and version 2 of my code..but not version 3.  (see code example below)

In anticipation of some replies, my rspec examples are in a separate project than my production code so its not a simple matter of versioning the examples with the code.  But if there is a better way to handle this, I'm open to alternatives.

Full example of what I want to do:

```
describe "using version as tags" do

  context "When I run 'rspec Dummy_spec.rb --tag version:2'"

  it "should run this test applicable to ver 1", :version =>1 do
    true.should eq(true)
  end

  it "should run this test applicable to ver 2", :version =>2 do
    true.should eq(true)
  end

  it "should not run this test applicable to ver 3", :version =>3 do
    true.should eq(true)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Relish page for the --tag option](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/command-line/tag-option) explains that you can exclude tags via `~key:value`, so you should be able to run `rspec Dummy_spec.rb --tag ~version:3` to run everything but the version 3 tests.